# Express 4 Sessions not persisting when restarting server

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-cookies

I have an Express 4 app setup to have sessions.

```
// Sessions
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: "some-secret" }));

// Signup
app.post("/signup", function (req, res) {
    create_user(req.body.user, function (err, user_id) {
        req.session.user_id = user_id;
        res.redirect("/admin");
    });
});
```

When I submit the form, it saves the user_id to the req.session. However, when I restart the server, the session is gone.

Why isn't it persisting? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The default session store for express-session is MemoryStore, which as the name suggests, stores sessions in memory only. If you need persistence, there are many session stores available for Express. Some examples:

- [Cookie store](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session)
- [Redis store](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis)
- [MongoDB store](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)
- [CouchDB store](https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-couchdb)
- [Riak store](https://github.com/frank06/connect-riak)
- [memcached store](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached)
- [leveldb store](https://github.com/wolfeidau/connect-leveldb)
- [MySQL store](https://github.com/nlf/connect-mysql)
- [PostgreSQL store](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple)
- [Firebase store](https://github.com/ca98am79/connect-firebase)

For a updated and more complete list visit [Compatible Session Stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores).

Comment: Cookie-session seems like it can be used as a replacement to express-session whereas for the rest, they are to be used along with express-session. 

How correct is the above understanding?

Answer (score 2):

@mscdex answer is great but in case you are looking for code samples. Here is one with connect-mongo which should work fine if you mongodb and mongoose.

Install the package:

```
npm i connect-mongo
```

require the package:

```
const session = require('express-session'); // You must have express-sessions installed
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
```

Now configure the session:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysecrets",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ 
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
     }),

  })
);
```

Again this assumes you are using mongoose and have the connection configured.

If you did everything right, it should work just fine.