# Can't store variables in express session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to build a session-based authentication for my web app. I have the following auth function:

```
function authenticate(req, res) {
  var body = req.body;

  getAuthUser(body.username, function (err, result) {

      if (hash(body.password) != result.password) {
          // invalid pass
          return;
      }

      req.session['user'] = result;
      res.redirect('/logged/panel');

      console.log(req.session); // 'user' session is displayed here
  });
}
```

I have also a middleware which ensures that user is authenticated when accessing secured content:

```
function validateRequest(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session); // 'user' session is not displayed here
  (req.session.user) ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
}
```

The problem is that my middleware does not see the stored variable by the `authenticate` function. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

This is how I use my middleware:

```
router.use(validateRequest);
```

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260676/express-4-sessions-not-persisting-when-restarting-server

Comment: @VladMatvei where and how you are registering `validateRequest` as middleware?

Comment: added the line of code where I link the middleware to my route

Answer (score 2):

You dont have `req` in the other function as it is out of [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). You can put req in global scope then you can access it in any other function `global.req=req` and then referencing to it in the other function with `global.req` as the function will have the req passed to in in scope instead of the one from the top frame

I now figured it out the router is running before `req.session.user` is set to `result`

Comment: `window`? in `nodeJS`?

Comment: I do have a req in my function. I can read other req properties but not the created session from authenticate function. I have added the line of code where I link my middleware to the route.

Comment: try just logging `req.session`

Comment: with `req.session` I do see a session but the `user` property is missing

Comment: the user property has not been created yet as your router is seeing the var when you are routing information(html)