# PassportJS and Express 4 not saving cookies / session correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, typescript

I have an app using Express 4 with Passport 0.3.2. I have set up a `passport-local` strategy, which is getting the correct user information when the `/session` endpoint is sent a username and password.

However the user information is never saved correctly. As such `req.user` is always undefined in all listeners and `req.isAuthenticated()` always returns false.

I have seen other posts which often find issues with the ordering of the middleware setup however I have ordered them in the correct way and so I am not sure where to go from here.

Here is my `POST` listener for `/session`:

```
app.post("/session",
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    (req: any, res: any) => {
        // if we reach this point, we authenticated correctly
        res.sendStatus(201);
    }
);
```

Here is my `LocalStrategy` setup:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    (username, password, done) => {
        let users = userRepository.getAll();

        let usernameFilter = users.filter(u => u.getUsername() === username);
        if (!usernameFilter || usernameFilter.length !== 1) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }

        if (!password || password !== "correct") {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }

        return done(null, usernameFilter[0]);
    }
));
```

Here is my app setup:

```
let app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'my secret key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I am using the following dependency versions:

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"express-session": "^1.13.0",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
```

---

I have added a callback to my `POST /session`, however an error is thrown. This is my callback:

```
app.post("/session",
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      session: false
    }),
    (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        req.logIn(req.user, (err: any) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });

        // if we reach this point, we authenticated correctly
        res.sendStatus(201);
    }
);
```

I get the following error thrown:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session

Comment: I believe you need to call passport's `.login()` function in your POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the passport docs:

> Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response.

---

Ah, good, we're making progress. You'll have to configure passport to serialize and deserialize the user information. See [this](http://passportjs.org/docs#sessions) for information. It should be noted that you will replace `User` with your own database access object.

Comment: Thanks @pulse0ne, I have added this and now am receiving an error. I have updated my main question.

Comment: @JamesMonger that's actually a good sign, you're closer to getting it working properly. I've update my answer

Answer (score 7):

I found this question from a Google search when I had a related problem.

What I realized was that `express-session` doesn’t persist sessions e.g. between server restarts. [Read here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23260884/449227).

So I swapped `express-session` for [`cookie-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session) instead:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'MyAppName',
    keys: ['very secret key'],
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 30 days
}));
```

And then PassportJS was persisting my sessions, no further change needed!

Answer (score 2):

Cookie-parser and body-parser are not necessary for this. Just `express-session` and `passport`.

It seems to me like your cookies are not being sent or received because of your express-session configuration (or lack thereof)

In order to consume cross-site cookies, the `sameSite` property needs to be set to `none`. However, if the `sameSite` property is set to `none`, the `secure` property is required to be set to `true`. Which will make it so the cookie is only sent through HTTPS. This doesn't work when developing on `http://localhost`.

To get around this, while in development `sameSite` can be set to "lax" and secure can be set to `"auto"`.

```
const inProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: true, // resave cookies even if nothing changed
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: `${inProd ? "none" : "lax"}`, // cross site // set lax while working with http:localhost, but none when in prod
      secure: `${inProd ? "true" : "auto"}`, // only https // auto when in development, true when in prod
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, // expiration time
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at @JamesMonger's question and @pulse0ne's answer, I figured out how to fix my problem. My session was not getting created as well in react with passport and cookie-session. I am sharing the problem code and the solution here, so that someone can benefit from it.
Old code that did not work

```
server.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google'),
(req, res) => {
     res.redirect('/api/current_user');
});
```

After adding session: true, the session got created and I was able to retrieve it from the request.

```
server.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {session: true}),
(req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/api/current_user');
});
```

Versions:

```
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-session": "^1.3.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
```